# Opening exe with parameters in Java, don't understand parameters

Tags: java, processbuilder

I'm aware how to open an exe program with parameters in Java from finding the answer online. However my specific shortcut is a bit complicated for me to understand.

I'm trying to open a shortcut which has the following target:

`C:\Windows\System32\javaw.exe -cp jts.jar;total.2012.jar -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -Dswing.boldMetal=false -Dsun.locale.formatasdefault=true -Xmx768M -XX:MaxPermSize=128M jclient/LoginFrame C:\Jts`

In my program I've split up the location and what I think are the parameters. However when I run the program I get the error `'Could not create Java Virtual Machine, Program will Exit'`. Can someone with a better understanding of whats going on explain what I might be doing wrong or point me in a direction where I can read up?

```
    String location = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\javaw.exe";
    String p1="-cp jts.jar;total.2012.jar"; 
    String p2="-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true";
    String p3="-Dswing.boldMetal=false";
    String p4="-Dsun.locale.formatasdefault=true";
    String p5="-Xmx768M";
    String p6="-XX:MaxPermSize=128M";
    String p7="jclient/LoginFrame" ;
    String p8 = "C:\\Jts";

try {
        Process p = new ProcessBuilder(location,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8).start();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Openprogramtest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: Does the shortcut work when you run it manually?

Comment: Try running the `Process` by only specifying the `location` parameter. If that works it means there is some error in the parameters

Comment: @Blorgbeard yup. It's a program that I installed that is widely used. Extreme Coders, if I run it without parameters its just running java

Comment: Try setting the working directory on the `ProcessBuilder` before calling `start()`

Comment: Each parameter should be past in separately, I suspect that `p1` is not been interpreted correctly. `"-cp jts.jar;total.2012.jar"` is been seen literally as a single parameter, try spliting so that `-cp` and `jts.jar;total.2012.jar` are past as individual parameters

Comment: Have you tried running this exact same command from the command line?  I ask because I've seen this issue when passing the "-Xmx" and the "-XX:MaxPermSize" flag with sizes that are problematic to the JVM.

Comment: @chamakits ok your onto something. I tried running that exact line in command prompt and it didn't open the program...Now I'm pretty confused why the exact line would work in a shortcut but not the command prompt

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each `String` you pass to `ProcessBuilder` is a separate argument (except the first one, which is the command).

Think of it like the `args[]` which are passed to your main method.  Each `String` would be a separate element in the array.

I suspect that `p1` is been interpreted as a single argument, when it should actually be two...

Try separating this argument into two separate parameters

```
String location = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\javaw.exe";
String p1="-cp"; 
String p2="jts.jar;total.2012.jar"; 
String p3="-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true";
String p4="-Dswing.boldMetal=false";
String p5="-Dsun.locale.formatasdefault=true";
String p6="-Xmx768M";
String p7="-XX:MaxPermSize=128M";
String p8="jclient/LoginFrame" ;
String p9 = "C:\\Jts";
```

**Amendment**

Look at the `-cp` parameter, it appears that the class path elements are relative to the location that the command is executed.  This suggests that you need to use the [`ProcessBuilder#directory(File)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#directory%28java.io.File%29) to specify the location that the command should executed from.

For example, if you program is installed in `C:\Program Files\MyAwesomeApp`, but you run it from the context of `C:\Desktop`, then Java won't be able to find the Jar files it needs, generally raising a `ClassNotFound` exception.

Instead, you need to tell `ProcessBuilder` that you want the command to executed from within the `C:\Program Files\MyAwesomeApp` context.

For example...

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(...);
pb.directory(new File("C:\Program Files\MyAwesomeApp"));
// Other settings...
Process p = pb.start();
```

**Updated from running example**

Just to make the point.  I built myself a little Java program that simple printed a simple message to the standard out.

When I run this, it works as expected...

```
try {
    String params[] = new String[]{
        "C:\\Windows\\System32\\javaw.exe",
        "-cp",
        "C:\\...\\TestSimpleProcessBuilder\\build\\classes",
        "-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true",
        "-Dswing.boldMetal=false",
        "-Dsun.locale.formatasdefault=true",
        "-Xmx768M",
        "-XX:MaxPermSize=128M",
        "testsimpleprocessbuilder/HelloWorld",
        "Boo"
    };
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(params);
    pb.redirectErrorStream();
    Process p = pb.start();
    InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
    int in = -1;
    while ((in = is.read()) != -1) {
        System.out.print((char) in);
    }
    is = p.getErrorStream();
    in = -1;
    while ((in = is.read()) != -1) {
        System.out.print((char) in);
    }
    System.out.println("p exited with " + p.exitValue());
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(TestSimpleProcessBuilder.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

When I change the arguments from

```
"-cp",
"C:\\...\\TestSimpleProcessBuilder\\build\\classes",
```

to

```
"-cp C:\\...\\TestSimpleProcessBuilder\\build\\classes",
```

It fails with...

[image]

And outputs

> Unrecognized option: -cp
> C:\DevWork\personal\java\projects\wip\StackOverflow\TestSimpleProcessBuilder\build\classes

And if you're wondering, this is the little test program I wrote that gets run...

```
package testsimpleprocessbuilder;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world - world says " + (args.length > 0 ? args[0] : "Nothing"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Gotta love down votes without comments.  Want to leave a comment as to why this might not be a suitable answer? Maybe give a poster a chance to redeem themselves?

Comment: Good afternoon, not sure who downvoted but it wasn't me. I will double check this answer when I get home today and can test it. I know yesterday when I did as you asked about splitting the -cp part, I didn't get an error but the program also didn't open. As mentioned in the previous comments, the program doesn't open in the command line, so now I'm thinking I might have the right parameters, just gotta figure out why it doesn't open from command line, but does open from double clicking the shortcut .lnk. Also definitely appreciate the help and just wanted to let you know I didn't downvote you.

Comment: @Chowza at least we fixed part of the problem. To my mind, the class path seems to be relative to the location the program is been executed from. This would suggest you my need to call [Process#directory(File)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#directory(java.io.File)) to set the working directory to the same location that the program is installed

Comment: @Chowza I added an amendment to fill out the previous comment

Comment: Adding a comment as I figured out my issue. I needed to change the directory on my processbuilder to c:/Jts in case anyone else wants to figure this out.

Comment: That's what I said in the "amendment" section :P

Comment: yea sorry I just thought specific to my question I'd clarify what made it work. and `-cp` definitely had to be a parameter of its own. Thanks for your help!